# How to accept both String and IntentFile for parameter in AppIntent?

Tags: ios, swift

I noticed that the **Show Result** action can accept a variety type of inputs. When we pass a string to it, it will display the string. And when we pass a HEIC file to it, it can display the image correctly.

But how to achieve it in swift code? I cannot figure it out though the official documentation.